# If JavaScript is dynamic scoping, what would be the last console.log() result in the following code?

Tags: scoping, dynamic-scope

This is how I defined the functions and the variable `x,y,z` is defined with some integer.

```js
var a = 0;
var x = 1;
var y = 2;
var z = 3;

function f(n) {
    a = n;
}
function g(){
    console.log(a);
}
function h(){
    f(x); g();
}
function k() {
    var a = 0; g(); f(y);
}
f(z); g(); k(); g(); h(); g();
```

The following is my thoughts on if the code above is **dynamically scope**:

```js
f(z){
  a = z; // The value of a became z
}
g(){
  console.log(a); // Printing out the value of z
}
k(){
  var a = 0;
  g(){
    console.log(a); // Printing out 0
  }
  f(y){
    a = y; // Assign the value of y to the variable a initialized 5 lines above
  }
}
g(){
  console.log(a); // Printing out the value of z
}
h(){
  f(x){
    a = x;
  }
  g(){
    console.log(a) // Printing out the value of x
  }
}
g(){
  console.log(a) // Printing out value of z or x ??
}
```

Not sure what the last console.log will output.

Comment: Have you tried running it to see?

Comment: can you provide [mcve] that contains *only* the one you confuse?

Comment: @PaulPhillips Yes, and since JS is static scope, it will output:
Value of z
Value of z
Value of y
Value of x
Value of x

Comment: what's the relation with `javascript`? what you want to know?

Comment: @appleapple There is no relation with JS, i just replicated a pseudo code with JS, and I'm looking for if it is dynamic scoping, what would be the last output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the example snippet with it's comments:

```js
var a = 0;
var z = 1;
var x = 2;
var y = 4;
function f(n) {
    a = n;
}
function g(){
    console.log(`value of var a is ${a}`); // output var a value to console
}
function h(){
    f(x);  // a becomes 2 here since x = 2
    g();  // output var a value to console
}
function k() {
    var a = 0; // this sets a to 0 only in function scope
    console.log(`function scope value of var a is ${a}`);
    g(); // output var a value to console which is 1 here not 0
    f(y); // a becomes 4 here since y = 4
}
f(z); 
g(); 
k(); 
g(); 
h(); 
g();
console.log(`final value of var a is ${a}`);
```

The below example works as you want (if i understood your question). Simply omit `var` before `a` in function `k()`.

```js
var a = 0;
var z = 1;
var x = 2;
var y = 4;
function f(n) {
    a = n;
}
function g(){
    console.log(`value of var a is ${a}`); // output var a value to console
}
function h(){
    f(x);  // a becomes 2 here since x = 2
    g();  // output var a value to console
}
function k() {
    a = 0; // this sets a to 0 only in function scope
    console.log(`function scope value of var a is ${a}`);
    g(); // output var a value to console which is 1 here not 0
    f(y); // a becomes 4 here since y = 4
}
f(z); 
g(); 
k(); 
g(); 
h(); 
g();
console.log(`final value of var a is ${a}`);
```

Comment: x, y, z are predefined in some random integer

Comment: @YZY add this to your post please.

Comment: Sorry for the confuse, I just added to the code

Comment: @YZY I have updated my answer using some default values for `x`,`y`,`z`.

Comment: Yes, that would be result of JS, but since JS is static scope, I'm looking for the result if the code is dynamically scope

Comment: @YZY you mean you want in the above example to change also the value of a to 0 in function `k()`?